# 0x378 port address in short int

Tags: c++, short, parallel-port

I have two methods:

```
short _stdcall Inp32(short portaddr);
void _stdcall Out32(short portaddr, short datum);
```

These are to access the ports of the ECP Parallel port. The problem is my data register's port address is 0x378 which is basically 888 in decimal.

Now, the data type of the portaddr, as is shown, is of type short. So what should I give my port address as: 888?

Comment: I don't get it. 0x378 and 888 are perfectly equivalent and the value can fit in a short, unless shorts on your platform are less than two bytes. How is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

"short" is system and compiler dependent, but it should be at least 16 bits. Therefore both of these should be fine:

```
short portaddr = 888;
short portaddr = 0x378;
```